# How to solve this grub problem on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, grub2, 18.04

I get a black screen with the following text when booting Ubuntu 18.04.

```
    GNU GRUB  version 2.02

    Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB  
    lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible  
    device or file completions.

grub> _
```

Comment: @karel is it possible loss my datas?

Comment: Does "loss of data" in your comment mean loss of data from Ubuntu or Windows? The message means something wrong happened with the bootloader (but not a loss of data). Nothing else can be said or suggested unless more information is given. Is Ubuntu standalone or in a dual boot with another OS? What happened exactly before the event, what were you doing, etc.? Please edit your own question with this additional information if you have it.